# wordpress pre_get_posts causing memory issue

Tags: wordpress, out-of-memory

I have a function which checks the current user role, and displays posts with certain meta keys that match the user role. Here is my code:

```
function wwp_exclude_products($query) {
    $exclude = array();
    $hide_products = get_option('wwo_hide_wholesale_prices');
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $featured = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ));

        if($hide_products){
            foreach($featured as $hide) {
                $user_price = get_post_meta($hide->ID, '_'.woo_get_user_role().'_price', true);
                if($user_price == NULL){
                    $exclude[] = $hide->ID;
                }
            }   
            $query->set('post__not_in', $exclude);
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wwp_exclude_products' );
```

This then generates a memory error on some sites i use this function on.

Here is the error:

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /www/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 2037?.
```

Is there a way i can resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of fetching all the posts `'posts_per_page' => -1` try fetching first 999 instead. If you have a big post count the query with `'posts_per_page' => -1` will have to go through ALL the posts. And the likelihood of one needing all the posts (showing or searching) is small.

Answer (score 0):

In place of first getting all excluded ids by looping, I would suggest you to directly check meta key. Like this

```
function wwp_exclude_products($query) {
  $hide_products = get_option('wwo_hide_wholesale_prices');
  $key = '_'.woo_get_user_role().'_price';
  if (  $hide_products && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_key', $key );
    $query->set( 'meta_value', '' );
  }
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wwp_exclude_products' );
```

If this didn't gives you desired result then you have to do some RND with `$query->set( 'meta_value', '' );`